# Candlestick charts in matplotlib - Jupyter notebook is not plotting

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I have been developing a trading bot and in the process, I am trying to make a live candlestick chart using matplotlib. The problem is that every time I run the Jupyter notebook (or iPython in Spyder), my plot does not show or this appears

```
 ([<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x113bee978>,
  <matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x1131204a8>,
  <matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x113095f28>,
  <matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x1131c3fd0>,
  <matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x1132ef160>,
  <matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x1132efa20>],
 [<matplotlib.patches.Rectangle at 0x11312f978>,
  <matplotlib.patches.Rectangle at 0x113120278>,
  <matplotlib.patches.Rectangle at 0x113061358>,
  <matplotlib.patches.Rectangle at 0x1131eafd0>,
  <matplotlib.patches.Rectangle at 0x1132ef390>,
  <matplotlib.patches.Rectangle at 0x1132effd0>])
```

I have tried to use %matplotlib inline and plt.show() and nothing seems to work. Here it follows the code I am using.

***By the way, I am using a Mac computer and Jupyter from Anaconda

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
from matplotlib.dates import date2num
from matplotlib.finance import candlestick_ohlc
import numpy as np
import requests
import time
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

def getNow(pair):
    return requests.get('https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnTicker').json()[pair]

def getPast(pair, period, daysBack, daysData):
    now = int(time.time())
    end = now-(24*60*60*daysBack)
    start = end-(24*60*60*daysData)
    base = 'https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnChartData&currencyPair='
    response = requests.get('{0}{1}&start={2}&end={3}&period={4}'.format(base, pair, start, end, period))
    return response.json()

pair = "USDT_BTC"    # Use ETH pricing data on the BTC market
period = 7200       # Use 7200 second candles
daysBack = 0       # Grab data starting 0 days ago
daysData = 15       # From there collect 15 days of data

# Request data from Poloniex
data = getPast(pair, period, daysBack, daysData)

# Convert to Pandas dataframe with datetime format
data = pd.DataFrame(data)

#Convert dates do float for matplotlib
data.date = data.date.astype(float)

#Define ohlc
date, closes, highs, lows, opens, volume = data['date'], data['close'], data['high'],data['low'], data['open'], data['volume']
ohlc = [date, opens, highs, lows, closes, volume]


#Plot with three regions
fig = plt.figure(facecolor='#f0f0f0')
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((6,1), (0,0), rowspan=1, colspan=1)
plt.title(pair)
plt.ylabel('H-L')
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((6,1), (1,0), rowspan=4, colspan=1, sharex=ax1)
ax2v = ax2.twinx()
plt.ylabel('Price')
ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((6,1), (5,0), rowspan=1, colspan=1, sharex=ax1)
plt.ylabel('MAvgs')

#Candlestick plot
candlestick_ohlc(ax1, ohlc, colorup='#77d879', colordown='#db3f3f')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Running your code as is, I get [this plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q52VS.png). So I guess it's hard to know what 's wrong on your side.

Comment: I am getting the same thing when I run everything together. When I just run the candlestick function, it happens what I said before. Do you need any more information to help me? Thanks

Comment: What does "I am getting the same thing when I run everything together." mean?

Comment: When I run this program in Spyder, I get the image you sent here (with three regions, but no data). When I run in Jupyter, if I run just the candlestick function in one line, I get that message pointing to the localization of the code or nothing happens (as I showed in the question)

Comment: by "line" you mean "cell"? In that case you still need to show the figure, `fig`.

Comment: Yes, the cell. My biggest problem now is that the figure is shown, but the data is not. I would like to know if I am referring something i the wrong way, maybe

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that the data inserted in the function was in a wrong format. That is the right way to define ohlc in this case:

```
date, closes, highs, lows, opens, volume = data['date'].tolist(), data['close'].tolist(), data['high'].tolist(),data['low'].tolist(), data['open'].tolist(), data['volume'].tolist()
ohlc = [tuple([date[i],opens[i],highs[i],lows[i], closes[i]
       ]) for i in range(len(date))]
```